# How can I add and splice items from array in same loop?

Tags: javascript

I need to loop through an array and add(push) and splice items. But in one array it is impossible for me right now.

```
this.unApprovedUser.forEach((user, index) => { 
  this.approvedUsers.push(user);
  // this.unApprovedUser.splice(user,  this.unApprovedUser.length); 
  this.userAssign(user);
  })

this.unApprovedUser.forEach((user, index) => { 
    // this.approvedUsers.push(user);
    this.unApprovedUser.splice(user,  this.unApprovedUser.length); 
    this.userAssign(user);
    })
}
```

This solution works but I need a better solution. Problem here is because when I push or splice item array is empty.

Comment: do you have sample data of `unApprovedUsers` and perhaps expected `approvedUsers`?

Comment: [ emailAddress: "kmmkkm@ddd.ddp"
id: 359
name: "mkkmmk"
surname: "mkmkkm"
userName: "nje5das" ]

Comment: the usage of splice does not make any sense. Supposed to be integers....

Comment: Have a sense I am using dag and drop...

Comment: The first parameter of `Array.splice()` is an integer, not an object like `user`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Take all the items in the array and assign them? And when you are done the array should be empty?

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of slice() is wrong, you do not pass in an object, it should be the start and end.

Seems like you are trying to take all the items from the array. Personally I would not use a forEach, I would just use a simple while loop.

```
while(this.unApprovedUser.length) {
  const user = this.unApprovedUser.shift(); // remove first item from array
  this.userAssign(user);
}
```

Other option is keep the each, but just clear the array when done.

```
this.unApprovedUser.forEach((user, index) => { 
  this.userAssign(user);
})
// clear the array
this.unApprovedUser.length = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to move unapproved users to the approved users list:

```js
let unApprovedUser = ['Joe', 'Mary', 'Bob']
let approvedUsers = []

for(let i=unApprovedUser.length-1; i>=0; i--){
  approvedUsers.push(unApprovedUser[i]);
  unApprovedUser.splice(i, 1);
}

console.log('unapproved:', unApprovedUser)
console.log('approved:', approvedUsers)
```

Or:

```js
let unApprovedUser = ['Joe', 'Mary', 'Bob']
let approvedUsers = unApprovedUser
unApprovedUser = []

console.log('unapproved:', unApprovedUser)
console.log('approved:', approvedUsers)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code line might be what you are looking for :

```js
this.unApprovedUsers = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.approvedUsers)).map((user,i) => (approvedUsers.shift(),assignUser(user),user))
```

implementation:

```js
let approvedUsers = ['a','b','c']
let unApprovedUsers = []

function assignUser(user) {}

unApprovedUsers = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(approvedUsers)).map((user,i) => (approvedUsers.shift(),assignUser(user),user))

console.log( approvedUsers )
console.log( unApprovedUsers )
```